# #Define macro in a function C++

Tags: c++, function, c-preprocessor

I wonder if there's a way to use a macro inside a function, for example if we have piece of code like this:

```
struct SomeStruct{
   int fancyVariableNumberOne;
   int notSoFancyVar;
};

void SomeFunction(SomeStruct *array)
{
   #define w(i) array[i].fancyVariableNumberOne;

   ...


}
```

I don't want to write `array[i].fancyVariableNumberOne` each time, can I somehow shorten it without changing struct?

Comment: Use `function` instead.

Comment: #define is a preprocessor reserved word. It will be used in COMPILATION, nothing related to execution...

Comment: you need typedef i guess

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply `#define w(i)` at the top of your file and then call `w(i)` in your function?

Comment: All preprocessor macros are, so to say, global once defined. The borders between the preprocessor and compiler are muddled in modern compilers, but you should still see it as a separate step that is performed before the actual compilation.

Comment: Did your compiler reject that code? It should work, but you should probably finish the function body with an `#undef w`.

Comment: If your objection is _writing_ that code, find a good IDE with decent code completion. If your objection is _reading_ it, I do not agree.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can define and use a macro like this. The only problem is that the macro will not be scoped to just that function. It will be visible from that point on in the entire translation unit (unless, as @MichaelKohne points out, you use `undef` to remove it.)

Rather than using a macro, try using an in-line function. It will be more flexible, and have fewer unintended side effects.

Comment: If the OP does use the macro inside the function, `#undef w` at the end of the function will at lease keep it from polluting the rest of the file's compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use macro, you might have some nasty unexpected side effects.

Instead use a lambda to capture `array` by reference and make it return `fancyVariableNumberOne`. C++11 is required

```
void SomeFunction(SomeStruct *array)
{
    auto w=[&array](int i){return array[i].fancyVariableNumberOne;};
    std::cout<<w(0)<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but what compilers support this at this time?

Comment: Every mainstream compiler. g++, MSVC, clang for the most famous ones

Comment: Intresting, I will look into this auto feature. Tbh it's the first time I'm seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are defined prior to compilation. Simply `define` your macro above and use it in your function. The pre-processor will paste whatever you've defined in the function.

For example:

```
#define w(i) array[i].fancyVariableNumberOne

void someFunction(SomeStruct *array)
{
    w(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make class that contains SomeStruct array and override [] operator to return fancyVariableNumberOne of each.

```
class SomeArray
{
SomeStruct *array;

public:
...
int operator[](int index)
{
return array[index].fancyVariableNumberOne;
}

};

SomeArray a;
...
int b = a[i];
```